# cannot generate insert statement for details array on json file although it work for master?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json.net, asp.net-core-2.1

**Problem**

cannot convert details array from json file to generate insert statement
and when reading from file to generate insert statement for details it give error

Accessed J Array values with invalid key value: "table". Int32 array index expected.'

for master_table my code work good without any problem but details array not work

```
public static class JsonHelper
    {
        public static string GetInsertStatement(JToken mastertoken)
        {
            return string.Format("INSERT INTO {0}({1}) VALUES({2});",
                mastertoken["table"],
                GetFieldParameterNames(mastertoken),
                GetFieldParameterNames(mastertoken, false));
        }

        static string GetFieldParameterNames(JToken mastertoken, bool fieldOnly = true)
        {
            string p = fieldOnly ? string.Empty : "@";
            return string.Concat(string.Join(", ", mastertoken["keys"].Cast<JProperty>().Select(jp => p + jp.Name)),
                ", ", string.Join(", ", mastertoken["fields"].Cast<JProperty>().Select(jp => p + jp.Name)));
        }

        public static List<SqlParameter> GetSqlParams(JToken mastertoken)
        {
            List<SqlParameter> para = new List<SqlParameter>();
            foreach (JToken jt in mastertoken["keys"])
                para.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + jt.ToObject<JProperty>().Name, jt.First));
            foreach (JToken jt in mastertoken["fields"])
                para.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + jt.ToObject<JProperty>().Name, jt.First));
            return para;
        }

        public static string GetInsertStatmentText(string JsonData)
        {
            string Insert = "";
            JObject jo = JObject.Parse(JsonData);
            JToken m = jo["details"];
            string connectionstring = "Server=sdfff-PC\\SQL2014;Database=sqlm;User Id=sa;Password=abc123;"; 
     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(JsonHelper.GetInsertStatement(m), connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    List<SqlParameter> lsp = JsonHelper.GetSqlParams(jo["details"]);
                    foreach (SqlParameter sqp in lsp)

                        command.Parameters.Add(sqp);


                     Insert = command.CommandText;
                }
            }

            return Insert;

        }
        program.cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string JsonData = File.ReadAllText("D:\\2.json");

            string insertStatment = JsonHelper.GetInsertStatmentText(JsonData);
        }
```

**Expected Result**

3 insert statement :

Expected Result is 3 statement insert :

```
// generated success

INSERT INTO master_table(id, branch_id, name, address, phone) VALUES(@id, @branch_id, @name, @address, @phone);

// cannot generated because error on first thread

insert into detail1_table(id,branch_id,LineNumber,ItemCode,Quantity,Price,Total) values (@id,@branch_id,@LineNumber,@ItemCode,@Quantity,@Price,@Total)


// cannot generate 


insert into detail1_table(id,branch_id,LineNumber,ItemCode,Quantity,Price,Total) values (@id,@branch_id,@LineNumber,@ItemCode,@Quantity,@Price,@Total)


only work for master and another for details not work
```

and when generate insert statement  for details give me error 
Accessed J Array values with invalid key value: "table". Int32 array index expected.'

json file

```
{
   "master" : {
       "table" : "master_table",
       "fields" : {
           "name" : "bar",
           "address" : "fleet street",
           "phone" : "555"
       },
       "keys":{
           "id" : 1,
           "branch_id" : 1
       }      
   },
   "details" : [
       {
           "table": "detail1_table",
           "keys":{
               "id" : 1,
               "branch_id" : 1 ,
               "LineNumber" : 1
           },
           "fields" : {
               "ItemCode" : "item-5050",
               "Quantity" : 10 ,
               "Price" : 50 ,
               "Total" : 500
           }
       },
       {
           "table": "detail1_table",
            "keys":{
               "id" : 1,
               "branch_id" : 1 ,
               "LineNumber" : 2
           },
           "fields" : {
               "ItemCode" : "item-9050",
               "Quantity" : 5 ,
               "Price" : 20 ,
               "Total" : 100
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `master` doesn't contain an array, but `details` does.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with https://app.quicktype.io?share=xOgfBwiXWqRLHzCT0Bst .